# Object reference error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have this piece of code:-
What I want is that in button click i want put some value in user control.
I get Object reference error.

```
if (Page.FindControl("pr1") is Control)
{
    Control previewControl = Page.FindControl("pr1");
    Label titleLabelPreview = (Label)previewControl.FindControl("titleLabel");
    titleLabelPreview.Text = emptxt.Text;
```

However, if i used it through master page it can not intialized
but if i use parent page it work properly. 
But here, one more problem persisted, suppose the scenario 
use a tab container
where is 3 tab panel
in first panel i used a button
when i click that button i want to change the tab panel view
means 2nd panel
but without refresh the page. and one important thing i don't want to use update panel on tab container. I do not wish to use ajax or javascript. any insight on this.
Also, would be really great if someone gives me a deep idea how to resolve object reference errors.
I read a few blogs like:_

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/62/Object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-and-INamingContainer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery.usernametemplate.aspx

however, was not fully satisfied.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Thanks John, I'll keep that in mind, could you please help me with the problem.

Comment: Your question is very confused. I don't think anyone will be able to answer it until you  get a better idea of what you're doing. The fact that you don't even seem to understand your "object reference error" is scary. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net